# What's your release process for your commercial application?

Tags: testing, release, production, procedure

If you are developing a commercial desktop application, what's your release process?

**Sample process:**

- Develop it: Patch bugs, add features, etc.
- Feature Freeze (*do not fix, add anything unless it's absolutely required*)
- Test it
- If everything is OK release it, if it's not fix it, test it, release it

I think the most crucial question is what's your approach to "**feature freeze > test > release**" cycle?

Or do you test it more frequently that you don't need such a cycle and your software is always ready for public release?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your QA budget. I've used both - using CI, at least on branch is always packaged and ready for release.

Feature-freeze > test > relase, the bigger QA budget, the shorter releases. Also, first stage is entirely dependand on release planning.

Also, how much developers test their work and how much coverage You have affect decision a lot.